# MySQL: handle EMPTY SET in UPDATE statement

Tags: mysql, sql

**I have:** something like

```
UPDATE table
SET field = (SELECT field FROM another_table WHERE id = @id);
```

**Problem:** `SELECT field FROM another_table WHERE id = @id` subquery can return one field or *EMPTY SET*.

**Question:** *How to handle situation when subquery returns empty set?*

**Updated:**

```
UPDATE table t
SET field = IF((SELECT field FROM another_table WHERE id = @id) IS NOT NULL, -- select field
  (SELECT field FROM another_table WHERE id = @id), -- Problem #1: select field AGAIN!
  (SELECT field FROM table WHERE id = t.id) -- Problem #2: try to not change value, so select the current field value!!
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If function can be useful:

```
UPDATE table
SET field = if((SELECT field FROM another_table WHERE id = @id) IS NULL,true,false);
```

Comment: I have `IF((SELECT field FROM another_table WHERE id = @id) IS NOT NULL, true_expr, false_expr)`. **Problem:** Actually my `true_expr` equals to `(SELECT field FROM another_table WHERE id = @id)`. **Question:** How to avoid selecting the sme value twice?

Comment: If both ID's are unique it should be ok. If not elaborate on your scenario.

Comment: look at *Updated* section of my question please

Answer (score 1):

You can add the conditional:

```
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM another_table WHERE id = @id) > 0
```

This will make sure that at least one row exists in `another_table` with the `id`.  See my [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fadce) as an example.

Note: this may not be the most efficient because it does a count on `another_table`, and if it is greater than 1 it will do another `SELECT` (two sub-queries).  Instead, you can do an `INNER JOIN`:

```
UPDATE table
INNER JOIN another_table ON table.id=another_table.id
SET table.field = another_table.field
WHERE another_table.id = @id;
```

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/098cc).  The reason why I saved this as a second option, is not all SQL languages can `UPDATE` with joins (MySQL can).  Also, you need some way to relate the tables..in this case I said that the `table.id` we are updating is equal to `another_table.id` we are taking the data from.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE** The `UPDATE` statement will modify EVERY row in `table` and assign the same value to every row; that seems a little unusual.

To answer your question:

If you want to handle the "empty set" by not updating any rows in `table`, then one way to do this is with a JOIN to an inline view:

```
UPDATE table t
 CROSS
  JOIN (SELECT a.field 
          FROM another_table a
         WHERE a.id = @id
         LIMIT 1
       ) s
   SET t.field = s.field
```

Note that if the inline view query (aliased as s) return an "empty set", then no rows in `table` will be updated, because the JOIN operation will also return an "empty set", meaning there are zero rows to be updated.